# Create an array of TaskSeries

Tags: java, jfreechart, gantt-chart

In JFreeChart, how can I create an array of `TaskSeries` for a Gantt chart?

The problem is that `TaskSeries` instance must be initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want `TaskSeries` array and then put them in a `TaskSeriesCollection`.

The straightforward approach seems to work:

```
TaskSeriesCollection model = new TaskSeriesCollection();
TaskSeries[] array = {new TaskSeries("One"), new TaskSeries("Two")};
for (TaskSeries taskSeries : array) {
    model.add(taskSeries);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`TaskSeriesCollection`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/gantt/TaskSeriesCollection.html), "A collection of `TaskSeries` objects." There's examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjfreechart%5D%20TaskSeriesCollection).

Comment: I want TaskSeries array and then put them in a TaskSeriesCollection!